# Phonegap VS Steroids. Did I choose well?

Tags: android, ios, performance, cordova, steroids

I want to develop an App for Android ann iOS. It is a very simple App where there are almost no server connections and it is pretty simple. The only things is that it will have many animations.

I thought that would be a good idea to choose Phonegap instead of a native application because it is multiplatform and it is very much easy to develop for a web developer like me.
But, when you read in the web you see a lot of people who say that it is really slow, that buttons doesn't react inmediatly and more things.

So first I would like to ask, Will the phonegap performance be enough for this kind of App.

And secondly, I have found Steroids. It looks great because it takes Phonegap and make it native. But it sounds too well, I mean, you have all of Phonegap with more performance, I guess it should have some problems.

So, could I use Stereoids instead of Phonegap to increase the performance? What it worse of Steroids?

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full disclosure, I'm an AppGyver employee and am of course inherently biased towards the Steroids platform, but here's a quick rundown of why you should choose us over PhoneGap:

- Theoretically, anything that can be done in PhoneGap can be done in Steroids as well. In reality, there are a few lingering problems with some custom plugins that might require some tweaking to work through our Build Service, but core Cordova plugins are supported.
- Steroids provides Native UI features to make your app virtually indistinguishable from an actual native app. We've gone to great lengths to ensure that the end user would not be able to tell a Steroids app from a fully native one. This includes eliminating the delay between button taps and the app reacting, as well as providing ready-made implementations for drawers, modals, tab bars and all the goodies that you would find in a native app, but have to build by hand in a PhoneGap app. Admittedly, this feature set is currently only available for iOS, but our Android support is catching up fast with the first UI features being in internal QA at the moment and more coming soon!
- Our qr code system makes demoing (and developing) apps insanely fast compared to having to constantly rebuild and install demo versions of your app. Just download the AppGyver Scanner, generate a share code and scan, and your app is now running on your phone.
- We provide support for a Chromium-based Android client, which blows the old Android WebViews out of the water in terms of performance and cross-platform compatibility. Once again, this is still a very young property, so full support for all Steroids features is not there yet, but Android is currently our top priority, meaning things will improve fast.

I am glossing over the details quite a bit here, but this should give you a general idea of what we feel makes our product great!

Comment: Is Android still behind?